# How to retrieve specific JIRA Fields in Java using RESTAPI

Tags: java, jira-rest-api

So far I am able to only establish a connection with Jira, but I don't know how I can fetch specific fields. From what I understand SearchResult class of JIRA API shall solve this problem but I don't know how to integrate it in my existing code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Java version - 8,
OS - Windows 10,
Eclipse - Mars

/* Jars used: 
    jersey-bundle-1.9.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.9)
    javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0-m02) */

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;
public class JiraData {
static ClientResponse response;

public static void main(String[] args) {


try
{

String auth = new String(Base64.encode("username" + ":" + "password"));
final String headerAuthorization = "Authorization";
final String headerAuthorizationValue = "Basic " + auth;
final String headerType = "application/json";
Client c = Client.create();


WebResource webResource = c.resource("https://jira.com");
response = webResource.header(headerAuthorization, headerAuthorizationValue).type(headerType).accept(headerType).get(ClientResponse.class);
String connectionresult = response.toString();
System.out.println(connectionresult); // returned a response status of 200 OK

if (response.getResponseStatus() != null && response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() == 200)
{
System.out.println("Connection Successful");
fetchFields();
}


}

catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(" Connection Error " + e);
}




}

private static void fetchFields() {

try
{

String jql = "project = SAMPLE";
/*
* Missing logic to Capture Jira fields like Ticket Number, Ticket URL, Issue Type, Ticket Status for project passed in jql
*/


}

catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(" Error from fetchFields method " + e);
}

finally
{
response.close();

}


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you want to use the `/search` endpoint (because you prepared a JQL statement), you can use a query parameter to determine which fields should be returned. Simply use a URL like `/search?fields=issuekey,summary,description` to define a list of fields to be returned (don't forget to define your JQL as well). The full list of available fields can be accessed with the `/field` endpoint, see [REST API docs here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/field-getFields). You can also find more query parameters for the `/search` endpoint in the [REST API docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search).